# Browser Javascript: setTimeout and the Main Program

Tags: javascript

When running in a browser, will `setTimeout` ever fire its code before the main program is done executing?  Have the major browser vendors agreed on this behavior, or is it a side-effect of implementation? (or have they agreed to keep this side-effect in as standard behavior)

Consider a very simple (and useless) program.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Timeout Called")
},1);
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++){};
console.log("done");
```

First we set a single micro-second `setTimeout` callback function which outputs `Timeout Called` to the console.

Then we spin in a loop for more than a micro-second.

Then we output `done` to the console.

When I run this program, it always outputs

```
done
Timeout Called
```

That is, the `setTimeout` callback functions aren't considered until the main program has run.

Is this reliable, defined behavior? Or are there times where the main program execution will be halted, the callback run, and then main program execution continued.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is defined behaviour. It is a common misconception that Ajax callbacks undeterministically execute at some time, possibly before the current execution path finishes, when in reality they will always execute some time afterwards.

Javascript is single threaded and will never return to the event loop until the current thread finishes executing completely.

An asynchronous function, such as an event handler (includes Ajax) or a function that is scheduled with setInterval/setTimeout will never execute before the current execution path completes.

Comment: ... barring browser bugs. Safari 5 had a bug for a while that would trigger "load" events from nested iframes, and those events would *preempt* running event handlers.

Comment: @Pointy I did not know about that bug. Thanks for pointing that out. Do you have a reference link I can add to my answer?

Comment: Well I only know because it caused some extremely weird behavior with jQuery.  I'll see if I can find the old bug I logged. I don't think it's really worth worrying about; after all, with Chrome getting an update about every 3 hours, anything might happen at any time :)

Comment: [Here is the ticket. Seems like yesterday, but it was almost 3 years ago!](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7344)

Answer (score 2):

This is **very well defined** behavior.

The browser is **not** async and still has to wait for a previous action to complete before it does the next action

Answer (score 1):

When using `timeOut`, it will wait first for the number of milliseconds that you passed, and then it will continue to wait until there is an opening in the code.  Generally, this means it will wait until the code is done.  The only exception (sort of) is when using other `timeOut`s or `setInterval`s.  For example, if your loop had been

```
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++){
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('One iteration');
    }, 15);

};
```

Your output would be

```
done
Timeout Called
One iteration
One iteration
```

And so on.